# img gets resized but div doesn't

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a parent div sized to max-width of 720px, a child image and a child div both sized to max-width of 100% and with display property set to block. The div contents a very long string, and the img a very wide image.

When the viewport is smaller than 720px, the image is properly resized. The div however takes the width of the string and ignores any overflow until it reaches 720px.

Can anyone explain why the img tag is resized to the viewport, while div is not?

```css
.container {
  max-width: 720px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.container img,
.container .content {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.swedavia.com/imagevault/publishedmedia/h1i0wnry5er12gtxsmxu/longchamp400.png">
  <div class="content">.........................................................................................................................................</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `<img>` **element** is resized. Not the tag.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone explain why the img tag is resized to the viewport, while
>   div is not?

Because of the **unbreakable** string, simple as that.

To solve this problem, set the `display` property of the parent, `.content` div,  to `inline`, add the `word-wrap: break-word` to enable wrapping and give the `.container` div the `width` of `100%` to make it responsive:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 720px;
  width: 100%; /* responsiveness */
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

/* solution */
.container .content {
  display: inline;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://www.swedavia.com/imagevault/publishedmedia/h1i0wnry5er12gtxsmxu/longchamp400.png">
  <div class="content">........................................................................................................................................................................................</div>
</div>
```